# Posgres SQl Stored Procedure In Clause issue

Tags: postgresql

Hi I want to Excute Stored Procedure Dynamicically
 where table name is also dynamic and at the end i have to pass branch Ids String.

when i executes sp is getting execited but when executing with my code getting error

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION dashboard.rspToGetBranchWiseTurnOverDataByRegionId(
  IN accountgropidcol numeric,
  IN BookingMonthCol numeric,
  IN BookingYearCol numeric,
  IN branchidcol character varying,
  OUT accountgroupid numeric,
  OUT sourcebranchid numeric,
  OUT destinationbranchid numeric,
  OUT waybilltypeid numeric,
  OUT totallr numeric,
  OUT totalbookingamount numeric,
  OUT totaldeliveryamount numeric,
  OUT grandtotalamount numeric,
  OUT totalquantiy numeric,
  OUT totalactualweight numeric,
  OUT totalchargedweight numeric,
  OUT bookingmonth numeric,
  OUT bookingyear numeric
 )
RETURNS SETOF record AS
$BODY$ 
DECLARE
    nameid          TEXT;   -- unique id for tables concat(Year,Month)
    tableName       TEXT;   -- table name
BEGIN 
    nameid = '_' || BookingYearCol || '_' || BookingMonthCol;
    tableName = 'dashboard.BranchWiseTurnOver' || nameid;

RETURN QUERY EXECUTE 'SELECT 
                accountgroupid, 
                sourcebranchid, 
                destinationbranchid, 
                waybilltypeid,
                totallr,
                totalbookingamount,
                totaldeliveryamount, 
                grandtotalamount,
                totalquantity,
                totalactualweight,
                totalchargedweight, 
                bookingmonth,
                bookingyear
                FROM '|| tableName || '
            where 
                accountgroupid  = ' || accountGropIdCol :: numeric || '
            AND bookingmonth    = ' || bookingMonthCol :: numeric || '
            AND bookingyear     = ' || bookingYearCol :: numeric || '
            AND SourceBranchId  = ' || any (string_to_array(branchidcol, ',')::numeric[]) || '' ;

END;
$BODY$  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
```

This is my stored procedure where i m getting error on any (string_to_array(branchidcol, ',')::numeric[]) this Line

error log is:

> ```
> ERROR: op ANY/ALL (array) requires operator to yield boolean
> Where: PL/pgSQL function dashboard.rsptogetbranchwiseturnoverdatabyregionid(numeric,numeric,numeric,character varying) line 9 at RETURN QUERY
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Finally Found Solution

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION dashboard.rspToGetBranchWiseTurnOverDataByRegionId(
  IN accountgropidcol numeric,
  IN BookingMonthCol numeric,
  IN BookingYearCol numeric,
  IN branchidcol character varying,
  OUT accountgroupid numeric,
  OUT sourcebranchid numeric,
  OUT destinationbranchid numeric,
  OUT waybilltypeid numeric,
  OUT totallr numeric,
  OUT totalbookingamount numeric,
  OUT totaldeliveryamount numeric,
  OUT grandtotalamount numeric,
  OUT totalquantiy numeric,
  OUT totalactualweight numeric,
  OUT totalchargedweight numeric,
  OUT bookingmonth numeric,
  OUT bookingyear numeric
 )
RETURNS SETOF record AS
$BODY$ 
DECLARE
    nameid          TEXT;   -- unique id for tables concat(Year,Month)
    tableName       TEXT;   -- table name
BEGIN 
    nameid = '_' || BookingYearCol || '_' || BookingMonthCol;
    tableName = 'dashboard.BranchWiseTurnOver' || nameid;

RETURN QUERY EXECUTE 'SELECT 
                accountgroupid, 
                sourcebranchid, 
                destinationbranchid, 
                waybilltypeid,
                totallr,
                totalbookingamount,
                totaldeliveryamount, 
                grandtotalamount,
                totalquantity,
                totalactualweight,
                totalchargedweight, 
                bookingmonth,
                bookingyear
                FROM '|| tableName || '
            where 
                accountgroupid  = ' || accountGropIdCol :: numeric || '
            AND bookingmonth    = ' || bookingMonthCol :: numeric || '
            AND bookingyear     = ' || bookingYearCol :: numeric || '
            AND sourcebranchid  IN (' || branchidcol :: Character varying || ')' ;

END;
$BODY$  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
```

Modified Stored Procedure Worked.